# Query Response for fetching receive payment records from quickbooks db?

Tags: php, quickbooks

Sorry for posting again. I m using consoilibytes quickbooks php api for developing app for quickbooks integration. I have written a code for getting receive payment response xml & parse its values to save in my mysql db. I have written some code but its giving error like invalid xml. pls help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is a working example for retreiving records from quickbooks database.

```
 function _quickbooks_receivepayment_query_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{   
$errnum = 0;
$errmsg = '';
$Parser = new QuickBooks_XML_Parser($xml);
if ($Doc = $Parser->parse($errnum, $errmsg))
{
    $Root = $Doc->getRoot();
    $List = $Root->getChildAt('QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRs/ReceivePaymentQueryRs');
foreach ($List->children() as $ReceivePayment)
    {

$TxnID=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet TxnID');
$TimeCreated= $ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet TimeCreated');
$TimeModified=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet TimeModified');
$EditSequence=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet EditSequence');
$TxnNumber=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet TxnNumber');
$CustomerRefListID=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet CustomerRef ListID');
$CustomerRefFullName=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet CustomerRef FullName');   
 $ARAccountRefListID=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet ARAccountRef ListID');
    $ARAccountRefFullName=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet ARAccountRef FullName'); 

$TxnDate=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet TxnDate'); 
 $TxnDateMacro=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet TxnDateMacro');
 $RefNumber=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet RefNumber');  


  $TotalAmount=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet TotalAmount');  
  $PaymentMethodRefListID=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet PaymentMethodRef ListID');  
  $PaymentMethodRefFullName=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet PaymentMethodRef FullName'); 

$Memo=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet Memo');
$DepositToAccountRefListID=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet DepositToAccountRef ListID');
 $DepositToAccountRefFullName=$ReceivePayment->getChildDataAt('ReceivePaymentRet DepositToAccountRef FullName');



  }
  }

 return true;
 }
```